# XMPPStreamManagement in iOS unable to send/receive acknowledgement and stanza id

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp

I am able to send messages to users which means i have a working and authenticated xmppStream.

But i am unable to send and receive acknowledgement from server. I want to know which message was received successfully by the server. I googled and found that XEP-0198 should be implemented for this. I am using ejabberd as XMPP server and it supports XEP-0198.

I tried that but i don't know if i am doing it right or not.

First of all i included the header file and added XMPPStreamManagementDelegate.

```
#import "XMPPStreamManagement.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,XMPPStreamManagementDelegate>
```

In the implementation file, here's how i have defined the stream.

```
XMPPStream *xmppS = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
[xmppS addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

XMPPStreamManagement  *xsm = [[XMPPStreamManagement alloc] init];
[xsm addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xsm activate:xmppS];
```

After that i connect with the server. After the connection is successful, i send an enable stanza.

```
NSXMLElement *enable = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"enable" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:sm:3"];
[xsm.xmppStream sendElement:enable];
```

Then i send a message

```
NSXMLElement *a = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"request" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:receipts"];
XMPPElement *e = [[XMPPElement alloc] initWithName:@"message"];
[e addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"123456"];
[e addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[e addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"testuser@myxmppserver.com"];
[e addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"testuser2@myxmppserver.com"];
[e addChild:a];
[xsm.xmppStream sendElement:e];
```

Test User receives the message and Test User 2 gets the received stanza.

```
<received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" id="123456"/>
```

My problem is if i send the following stanza, i receive no message.

```
NSXMLElement *r = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"r"];
[xsm.xmppStream sendElement:r];
```

I have implemented the following function

```
-(void)xmppStreamManagementDidRequestAck:(XMPPStreamManagement *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"ACK");
}
```

But still nothing gets printed.
Please help. Also, how can i know when the server has received the sent message.

Let me know if anyone wants to know any other part of code from my side.

Comment: The 'enable' element is not a Stanza, it just a plain stream element. All other elements defined by xep198 are also not stanzas.

Comment: So how should i go ahead and receive message acknowledgement?

Comment: @VitulGoyal can you resolve this problem, i am also facing same problem with XMPPStreamManagement, please suggest me what u done for this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions in xmppStreamManagement for sending the request and get received id:

```
[xmppStreamManagement requestAck];
```

and

```
- (void)xmppStreamManagement:(XMPPStreamManagement *)sender wasEnabled:(NSXMLElement *)enabled 

- (void)xmppStreamManagement:(XMPPStreamManagement *)sender didReceiveAckForStanzaIds:(NSArray *)stanzaIds
```

make sure the stream management is enabled by:

```
[self.xmppStreamManagement enableStreamManagementWithResumption:YES maxTimeout:0];
```