# XMPPStreamManagement receive message acknowledgement from server

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp

I am using XMPPFramework for iOS and have ejabberd as XMPP Server. I want to receive acknowledgement for a message i send to the server.

```
XMPPStream *xmppS = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
[xmppS addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

XMPPStreamManagement  *xsm = [[XMPPStreamManagement alloc] init];
[xsm addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xsm activate:xmppS];

NSXMLElement *a = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"request" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:receipts"];
XMPPElement *e = [[XMPPElement alloc] initWithName:@"message"];
[e addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"123456"];
[e addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[e addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"testuser@myxmppserver.com"];
[e addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"testuser2@myxmppserver.com"];
[e addChild:a];
[xsm.xmppStream sendElement:e];
```

The message is successfully received by the recipient but how can i know if the server has received the message?

Comment: refer to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615170/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615170/